# MySQL C API Initialization in Multi-Threaded Program

Tags: mysql, c, linux, multithreading

I'm on Linux using the MySQL 5.5 C API.

My program starts in a single main thread and then spawns lots of worker pthreads.  The worker threads need to make database transactions.

So there are two functions in my program:

```
foo_init_main_thread() // called once before any worker threads are started

foo_init_worker_thread() // called from a worker thread
                         // immediately after it has started
```

It is not clear how to initialize MySQL in this enviornment.  The documentation is really unclear.

Inside `foo_init_main_thread` and `foo_init_worker_thread` which of `mysql_thread_init`, `mysql_library_init`, `mysql_init`, `mysql_connect` do I need to call and in what order?

Do I need to have one database handle per thread or can the worker threads all share a database handle?

The documentation is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c.html

Comment: Have you read [How to Write a Threaded Client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/threaded-clients.html)? I think it pretty much answers all your questions.